# http party: `connect': Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, opensuse, httparty

I am using Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.3, Linux OpenSUSE

Using HTTParty gem, I am calling https url but it throws following error.

> `connect': Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Can someone guide on this ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the ssl version to v3? http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#ssl_version-instance_method

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug in Httparty, it is due to a bug in Apache/Tomcat and Macs running updated versions of OpenSSL.

see this [link](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/257) to know about this bug, and refer this [post](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/05/tls-error-with-ruby-client-and-tomcat-server/) for the solution.